# Open Source C++ game engine math libraries?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm looking for a free to use game engine math library. Specifically I'd like a good matrix and vector implementation. And everything needed to move objects in 3D space.  Does anyone know any good ones?  I'm targeting [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL).  I'd like to write them myself but don't have the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](http://glm.g-truc.net/)

Though if you want physics with your math you could go with [Bullet Physics Library](http://www.bulletphysics.com/wordpress/)

Finally if you want an entire engine i'd go with [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/)

Comment: I think GLM will work nicely... seems light weight enough and has what I need

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider [Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/).

Answer (score 2):

Besides [Ogre 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/), there's also [Crystal Space](http://www.crystalspace3d.org).  Here's an [article](http://www.arcanoria.com/mmorpg/CS-Ogre.php) that compares the two.

Comment: That article appears to 404 on me.

Comment: @darthcoder, it looks like arcanoria.com did some reorganizing. I've updated the article's URL, accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you want an entire 3D engine (which of course would contain the 3d maths you need) see [Ogre 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) (LGPL)

Comment: Actually MIT license now for current svn trunk and all coming releases.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mg3d/

It is an opensource engine that has all former OpenGL transformation routines. The implementation here is very straightforward and clear. And it is very easy to include the module with the routines in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have good work with Open Dynamics Engine is Full and Stable Physics Engine,
the ode in a BSD License, and have some functions for Matrix Manipulation, Quaternion and rotations.